# Displaying Div Elements next to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make a simple game of hangman, and am stuck at this step.
I'm trying to display the alphabet in a horizontal line and make each letter clickable. Here is what I have right now in my html file.

```css
#letters {
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p1>
  Guess the Word in 5 or less guesses
  <br>Click on each letter to guess the word
</p1>


<div id="letters">

  <div id="a">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  <div id="c">
    <p>c</p>
  </div>
  <div id="d">
    <p>d</p>
  </div>
  <div id="e">
    <p>e</p>
  </div>
  <div id="f">
    <p>f</p>
  </div>
  <div id="g">
    <p>g</p>
  </div>
  <div id="h">
    <p>h</p>
  </div>
  <div id="i">
    <p>i</p>
  </div>
  <div id="j">
    <p>j</p>
  </div>
  <div id="k">
    <p>k</p>
  </div>
  <div id="l">
    <p>l</p>
  </div>
  <div id="m">
    <p>m</p>
  </div>
  <div id="n">
    <p>n</p>
  </div>
  <div id="o">
    <p>o</p>
  </div>
  <div id="p">
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
  <div id="q">
    <p>q</p>
  </div>
  <div id="r">
    <p>r</p>
  </div>
  <div id="s">
    <p>s</p>
  </div>
  <div id="t">
    <p>t</p>
  </div>
  <div id="u">
    <p>u</p>
  </div>
  <div id="v">
    <p>v</p>
  </div>
  <div id="w">
    <p>w</p>
  </div>
  <div id="x">
    <p>x</p>
  </div>
  <div id="y">
    <p>y</p>
  </div>
  <div id="z">
    <p>z</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="spots">
  <p>_ _ _ _ _ _</p>
</div>
```

I've looked at other posts, but they don't seem to solve my problem.

Also I'm a bit confused on the difference between a `div class` and a `div id`.

Comment: *"I'm a bit confused on the difference between a div class and a div id."* - Id's are unique and can only be applied to one element, while a class can be shared by more than one element.

Comment: I like to think of an **id as a first name** of an element and the **class as a last name** that is shared among siblings.

Comment: I would use `display: flex;` property for `#letters` wrapper. Also don't use IDs in selectors. To do onclick events make sure that each of the letter share same class name. `<div class="letter" id="a">`

Answer (score 3):

You are only making the wrapping div `inline-block` you need to apply this style to each of the letters.

You could do this by adding a `class` to all of the letters such as:

```
<div id="a" class="letter">a</div>
<div id="b" class="letter">b</div>
```

Then in your css apply `inline-block`

```
.letter{ display: inline-block }
```

You could also do this without the `classes` like so:

```
#letters > div { display: inline-block }
```

You can have multiple `elements` using the same `class` and an `element` can have multiple `classes` (separated by spaces) where as `ids` should be `unique` for each `element` and `elements` may only contain 1 `id`

Answer (score 1):

Answering your doubt, regards to ID vs Class you can read this great article  [The differences between ID and class](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Where one of the big difference is:

#### ID IS UNIQUE - CLASS ARE NOT UNIQUE

---

Regards to your issue in hand

you need to make your letters inline, because you are using `div` - which is a block level element - so a way to do that is set to `inline-block` to it.

---

**EDIT**

> Great thank you. That works. How would I now move this whole element
>   to a specific spot on the screen. The usual options don't seem to
>   work. When I use right, top, bottom, it makes the letters go vertical
>   again.

the snippet was updated, you can achieve that using `position:relative/absolute`

```css
#letters > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.hangman-game-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
/*move the game here*/
.hangman-game {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin: auto;
  /*change the width as you wish*/
  width: 300px 
}
```

```html
<div class="hangman-game-wrap">
  <div class="hangman-game">
    <p1>
      Guess the Word in 5 or less guesses
      <br>Click on each letter to guess the word
    </p1>
    <div id="letters">
      <div id="a">
        <p>a</p>
      </div>
      <div id="b">
        <p>b</p>
      </div>
      <div id="c">
        <p>c</p>
      </div>
      <div id="d">
        <p>d</p>
      </div>
      <div id="e">
        <p>e</p>
      </div>
      <div id="f">
        <p>f</p>
      </div>
      <div id="g">
        <p>g</p>
      </div>
      <div id="h">
        <p>h</p>
      </div>
      <div id="i">
        <p>i</p>
      </div>
      <div id="j">
        <p>j</p>
      </div>
      <div id="k">
        <p>k</p>
      </div>
      <div id="l">
        <p>l</p>
      </div>
      <div id="m">
        <p>m</p>
      </div>
      <div id="n">
        <p>n</p>
      </div>
      <div id="o">
        <p>o</p>
      </div>
      <div id="p">
        <p>p</p>
      </div>
      <div id="q">
        <p>q</p>
      </div>
      <div id="r">
        <p>r</p>
      </div>
      <div id="s">
        <p>s</p>
      </div>
      <div id="t">
        <p>t</p>
      </div>
      <div id="u">
        <p>u</p>
      </div>
      <div id="v">
        <p>v</p>
      </div>
      <div id="w">
        <p>w</p>
      </div>
      <div id="x">
        <p>x</p>
      </div>
      <div id="y">
        <p>y</p>
      </div>
      <div id="z">
        <p>z</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="spots">
      <p>_ _ _ _ _ _</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thank you. That works. How would I now move this whole element to a specific spot on the screen. The usual options don't seem to work. When I use right, top, bottom, it makes the letters go vertical again.

Comment: Use javascript to append `<p></p>` from parent's id.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. Each element has its click event. Also it can be simplified even more if you create each element dynamicaly using jQ.

```js
$(".letter").each(function() { 
  // gets id from attribute
  var letter =  $(this).attr("id");
  // create element <p> inside .letter
  $(this).append("<p>" + letter + "</p>");
  // assign click event for each .letter
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    // TO DO when clicked
    $("#letterClicked").text("Clicked " + letter);
  });
});
```

```css
#letters{
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.letter {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="letters">
  <div class="letter" id="a"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="b"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="c"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="d"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="e"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="f"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="g"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="h"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="i"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="j"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="k"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="l"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="m"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="n"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="o"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="p"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="q"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="r"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="s"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="t"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="u"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="v"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="w"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="x"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="y"></div>
  <div class="letter" id="z"></div>
</div>
<div id="letterClicked"></div>
```